# Input type text with fraction

Tags: html, forms

I want to make it possible for visitors of my website to add fraction in a input text field.
So if they push the '/' or a specific button on my website, in the text field a fraction line should popup and a number can be added in the numerator and denominator.
The same I would do for the exponent, when push the '^' or a specific button.

[edit] Maybe my question wasn't clear. I tried to create it myself, but I have really no idea how to start. I can create it in two separated fields, but I want the visitor to choose if he has to add a fraction. 
I saw the solution in a flash website, but I thought with the introduction of html 5, flash would disappear.

Comment: I would just add different input fields and show or hide them based on which button they click, so if they chose the fraction button show two input fields, one for numerator and one for denominator.

Comment: A good practice will be if you try to do it. Don't get me wrong, we love helping people. But it is really important to test your curiosity and finding a way of solving problems. And when ever you are stock, your questions will surely be answered. See the [How to, Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 3):

This is the best solution i can come up. I dont really know how you would make a fraction like this in an input field.

Hope it helps

```js
$('#input-main').change(function(){
  $('.main').html($('#input-main').val());
})

$('#input-denom').change(function(){
  $('.denom').html($('#input-denom').val());
})

$('#input-num').change(function(){
  $('.num').html($('#input-num').val());
})
```

```css
p {display: inline-block}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<lable for="input-main">Number</lable>
<input id="input-main" type="text" value="">
<lable for="input-num">Numerator</lable>
<input id="input-num" type="text" value="">
<lable for="input-denom">Denominator</lable>
<input id="input-denom" type="text" value="">

<p class="main" >1</p><sup class="num">1</sup>&frasl;<sub class="denom">2</sub>
```

Comment: @user2051376 Did my answer help you, or did you ran into trouble?